# JS object sorting using coupled ID

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have an array of objects:

```
{name: "bla-1", price: 100 }
{name: "bla-1", price: 150 }
{name: "bla-1", price: 150 }
{name: "bla-2", price: 600 }
```

I need the output on page to look this like

```
bla-1 (100) - 1
bla-1 (150) - 2
bla-2 (600) - 1
```

Can't find solution for this sorting. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Array `reduce` and `map` methods:

```
reduced = data.reduce(function (previous, current) {
        var string = current.name + " (" + current.price + ") - ";
        if (!previous[string]) {
            previous[string] = 1;
        } else {
            previous[string]++;
        }
        return previous;
    }, {});
final = Object.keys(reduced).map(function (key) {
    return (key + reduced[key])
});
```

(where `data` contains your array of objects)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/8rgJ7/)